# CSS fill parent height reloaded

Tags: html, css

I have this example for the very known fill-parent height problem: http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9bM4/379/ I've really tried to find a solution by googling but I cannot find anything for these requirements:

- The height of the element is **not** known, neither by percentage nor by absolute size. So `position: absolute; top: ?px; bottom: 0px` would not work
- The upper box should only take up the space it needs for its content, so with my little knowledge about flexbox, it seems that I cannot use it either (just used it in the example because this is kind of as closest as I got)
- The outer container has a fixed height (90% of the body in this example)

It would be nice if `flex: 1` in each container, is kind of the maximum growth of the upper container. Is this even possible with css yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I'm assmuning you would like the second container to use whatever space is left over after the first container is sized to its content.

If so, set the `.content` class with `height:0` and `flex-grow:1`

UPDATED EXAMPLE:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9bM4/385/

Comment: Like this both containers use 50% of the height. The upper container should only take up as much height as it has content (with a maximum of 50%)

Comment: Updated the answer with a working solution.  Both containers have the same class name.  So I targeted just the last one with CSS to make it flexy.  Alternatively you could apply an additional class name to the container you want to be flexy.

Comment: Updated again to make the first container `max-height: 50%`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem was that you gave the container id height:90%; so it will have to forcefully cover inside it, which is not posibble, So change it with height:auto;.
This will solve your problem

[JSFiddle : Updated](http://fiddle.jshell.net/47oeqn8f/)

**CSS : Code to change** (Edited)

```
#container
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 90%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border:2px solid green;
}

.content:nth-child(2)
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.content{
    border:1px solid red
};

.text
{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The fixed height of the outer container is actually a requirement. I'll update the question

Comment: Thats not filling up the parents height. It makes the parent scrollable, giving it an unlimited height. The height of the non-scrollable parent is fixed though.

Comment: `overflow: auto` is not a solution as the parent container should not be scrollable. The height of the parent container must be fixed. `position: fixed` is also not what I want

Comment: Try to scroll completely down in the second container 8-))

Comment: '.content:nth-child(2)
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 60%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
 }
.text
{
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border:5px solid yellow;
}'

Comment: Replace above code, i think this is the only solution as the class "content" are same for both blocks now if you switch to mobile device than you will need a Media Queries and in that change height of .content:nth-child(2) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77755/discussion-between-divy3993-and-ohcibi).